# Reading yaml properties file from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, mule4

I have a yaml properties file stored in a S3 bucket. In Mule4 I can read this file using S3 connector. I need to use properties defined in this file (for dynamic values reading and using it in Mule4) in DB connectors. I am not able to create properties from this file such that I can use them as ${dbUser} in mule configuration or flow as an example. Any guidance on how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use the S3 connector to do that. The connector can read the file in an operation at execution time, but properties placeholders, like ${dbUser} have to be defined earlier, at deployment time.

You might be able to to read the value into a variable (for example: #[vars.dbUser]) and use the variable in the database connector configuration. That is called a dynamic configuration, because it is evaluated dynamically at execution time.

Comment: thanks for your input. do you some sample mule code for me to understand it more clearly? And then try it out before I can accept your suggestion as answer.